# sql how to insert into a column like it was an identity column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table with three columns

```
KeyID   | nvarchar(10)  
ColumnA | nvarchar(max)  
ColumnB | Nvarchar(max)
```

What i'm trying to do is a select insert, however with keyID i need to treat it like an indentity column.

For example if I had 3 rows I wanted to insert it would be :

```
1001 | Apple     | Pear  
1002 | Pear      | Mango  
1003 | Pineapple | Pine
```

But i'm trying to do this with an insert select, for example:

```
insert into myTable(KeyId,ColumnA,ColumnB) select 'x',OrigColA,OrigColB from myTableB
```

obviously 'x' is where i'm having the issue.

Thanks in advance!

This is no KeyId located in myTableB

Comment: And why not just use an IDENTITY column?  Why reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit ugly because of the varchar, but you can try:

```
;WITH x AS
(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY OrigColA, OrigColB) AS n, OrigColA, OrigColB
  FROM myTableB
)
INSERT INTO myTable(KeyId, ColumnA, ColumnB)
SELECT (SELECT CAST(CAST(MAX(KeyId) AS INT) + n AS NVARCHAR(10)) FROM myTable),
    OrigColA, OrigColB
FROM x;
```

This of course assumes there is already a row in `myTable` to get the current maximum value from.

[SQL Fiddle example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5718f/9)

If that's not always true, wrap `MAX(KeyId)` with a `COALESCE` and the constant of one less than your starting default. For example:

```
;WITH x AS
(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY OrigColA, OrigColB) AS n, OrigColA, OrigColB
  FROM myTableB
)
INSERT INTO myTable(KeyId, ColumnA, ColumnB)
SELECT (SELECT CAST(CAST(COALESCE(MAX(KeyId),1000) AS INT) + n AS NVARCHAR(10)) FROM myTable),
    OrigColA, OrigColB
FROM x;
```

Or if you *know* there isn't a row and you just want to start at a constant, just do:

```
INSERT INTO myTable(KeyId, ColumnA, ColumnB)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY OrigColA, OrigColB) + 1000, OrigColA, OrigColB
FROM myTableB
```

Answer (score 0):

you need a db with sequences.  heres a workaround for sql server

http://www.sqlteam.com/article/custom-auto-generated-sequences-with-sql-server